# Sed handle patterns over multiple lines

Tags: regex, linux, sed

For example if I have a file like

```
yo@gmail.com, yo@
gmail.com yo@gmail
.com
```

And I want to replace the string `yo@gmail.com`.
If the file had the target string in a single line then we could've just used

```bash
sed "s/yo@gmail.com/e@email.com/g" file
```

So, is it possible for me to catch patters that are spread between multiple line without replacing the \n?

Something like this

```
e@email.com, e@
email.com e@email
.com
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you mean you want to keep 3 lines in the result, it is not quite possible with one simple pattern. If you want to get `e@email.com, e@email.com e@email.com` line in the end, it is quite easy.

Comment: Why isn't `yo@` replaced with `e@e` ??  Why isn't `yo@gmail` replaced with `e@email.` ??  If there are restrictions that the line breaks are on word boundaries, and that the match and replacement email addresses should replace at boundaries as well, then the question is much better constrained.   Your suggested output is following those rules, but you haven't made it entirely clear there's a line-break on word-boundary restriction in the input.

Comment: How would you replace "y\no@gmail.com"? Is it "e\n@email.com" or "\ne@email.com"?

Comment: @stevesliva the linebreaks can be anywhere. and thats the main problem.
I think it's not possible and it would be much easier if i use python or perl

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
tr -d '\n' < file | sed 's/yo@gmail.com/e@email.com/g'
```

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to add a minor detail, can I do this without changing the files original shape?

Comment: That is not really a *minor* detail. It is not possible with sed. You would need perl, Python, ruby and perhaps awk.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do it with python now

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;s/yo@gmail\.com/e@email.com/g
        h;s/(\S+)\n(\S+)/\1\2\n\1/;/yo@gmail\.com/!{g;P;D}
        s//\ne@email.com/;:a;s/\n(\S)(\S+)\n\S/\1\n\2\n/;ta
        s/(.*\n.*)\n/\1/;P;D' file
```

Append the following line to the pattern space.

Replace all occurrences of matching email address in both the first and second lines.

Make a copy of the pattern space.

Concatenate the last word of the first line with the first word of the second and keep the second line as is. If there is no match with the email address, revert the line, print/delete the first line and repeat.

Otherwise, replace the match and re-insert the newline as of the length of the first word of the second line (deleting the first word of the second line too).

Remove the newline used for scaffolding, print/delete the first line and repeat.

N.B. The lines will not be of the same length as the originals if the replacement string length does not match the matching string length. Also there has been no attempt to break the replacement string in the same relative split if the match and replacement strings are not the same length.

---

Alternative:

```
echo $'yo@gmail.com\ne@email.com' |
sed -E 'N;s#(.*)\n(.*)#s/\\n\1/\\n\2/g#
       :a;\#\\n([^/])(.*)\\n(.)?(.*/g)#{s//\1\\n\2\3\\n\4/;H;ba}
       x;s/.//;s#\\n/g$#/g#gm;s#\\n/#/#;s/\./\\./g' |
sed -e 'N' -f - -e 'P;D' file
```

or:

```
echo 's/yo@gmail.com/e@email.com/' |
sed -E 'h;s#/#/\\n#g;:a;H;s/\\n([^/])/\1\\n/g;ta;x;s/\\n$//mg;s/\./\\./g' |
sed -zf - /file
```

N.B. With the last alternative solution, the last sed invocation can be swapped for the first alternative solutions last sed invocation.